# are foreign key relationships for address table necessary

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

**EDIT:** I think I worded this wrong. Please read foreign keys as foreign key constraints. I realize I need the client id in the address table, etc.

I have a client table.
id | pref_name | full_name | business_name | etc . . .

I realized the client can have multiple locations/addresses so I have an address table.
id | client_id | name  | address1 | address2 | sub_area_id | area_id | province_id | country_id | postcode | etc . . .

Then I realized clients can come from multiple countries so I added:
country table
id | country | code (ISO-2A)

province table
id | name | country_id

area table
id | name | province_id

sub area table
id | name | area_id

So now I realize that I don't need all of sub_area_id | area_id | province_id | country_id in the address table.

From sub_area_id I can get the rest with a join query, however, there will not always be a sub area id. There WILL always be an area id. I guess I do need sub_area_id | area_id but can remove province_id | country_id from the address table

What I am not sure of is do I need foreign keys for the country, province, area, sub_area table with each other?

It seems that if a country is deleted so should all relating data in the other tables, but I am pretty sure that a country will never be deleted. Same for provinces, areas, sub_areas. Is it a waste of time implementing foreign keys?

Also a client might be disabled (not deleted because it would affect historic data) so can a foreign key also disable the client addresses, or is it just not necessary to disable them? Again, its probably not best to delete them as the client may resume later on.

Any suggestions for improvement on my structure?
TIA

Comment: A FK declaration just says subrow values somewhere must appear elsewhere. So declare every FK you can unless it's implied by others or it causes a cycle & your DBMS can't handle a cycle. However having info in a table that can be got from another must be managed even if constraints complain when the managing isn't done. Re deleting read about 'soft deletes' & about 'historical data'. A classic DB case of this is a filled order that is kept as it was on filling regardless of how things have changed since. PS Names change. Countries etc come & go.

Comment: @philipxy - thanks. I hadn't heard the term soft delete before. I found some good info on SO and will implement that anywhere data can be deleted that may be required later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely you need foreign key to refer the address of client. if you have not the id of the client in address table, you have no way to retrieve address of your client from address table

Comment: Thanks. I realize that. I am not clear on terminology so maybe I worded my question incorrectly. I edited it to try and make it clearer what i was asking.